# Doctrine column names case sensitivity

Tags: sql-server, doctrine, pdo

I'm trying to query mssql database with Doctrine. I set up connection, built schema from database and built classes. All went smoothly, but now when I try to query database:

```
symfony doctrine:dql "from TABLE_NAME"
```

I get an error Invalid column name 'column_name', because our mssql database server is setup to use CASE SENSITIVE and UPPER CASE column names, whereas doctrine is forcing all my column names to be lower case. How do I set up doctrine to either preserve sensitivity (better) or make them upper case?

Answer (score 3):

look at the link

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/configuration/en

```
$conn->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_PORTABILITY,
        Doctrine_Core::PORTABILITY_FIX_CASE )
```

Comment: As manual says "The case depends on the field_case option that may be set to either CASE_LOWER (default) or CASE_UPPER". Where do I set field_case option?

Comment: $conn->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_FIELD_CASE, CASE_UPPER);

Comment: This doesn't help me.. I've checked everything thoroughly, but column names are still lowercase. Have you tried this? Is there some other way to solve the problem? Maybe setup a hook, when query is build and do strtoupper manually?

Comment: the code is in IMPORT/MSSQL.PHP LINE 210,   if ($this->conn->getAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_PORTABILITY) & Doctrine_Core::PORTABILITY_FIX_CASE) {
            if ($this->conn->getAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_FIELD_CASE) == CASE_LOWER) {
                $keyName = strtolower($keyName);
                $pkName  = strtolower($pkName);
            } else {
                $keyName = strtoupper($keyName);
                $pkName  = strtoupper($pkName);
            }
        }

Comment: also try $conn->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_FIELD_CASE,  CASE_NATURAL):

Comment: So, the code is in listTableViews($table) function. But I cant find no reference to this function in the code. I tried debugging - this function is never called during the request. Should I call it manually?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid digging up into the configuration. Use `""` in your declarations.
This makes the column name case-sensitive for some databases like PostgreSQL.

Example:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="""Apples""", referencedColumnName="applies")
```