# Configure DBAL via Symfony2 to return lowercase keys

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm using the Doctrine 2 DBAL (but not ORM) in Symfony2 PR9. When I execute the following

```
$conn = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.aademo_connection');
$user = $conn->fetchAssoc('SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 1');
```

Then all the keys in the returned array have the same slightly erratic capitalization that the database columns have. Unfortunately, I can't randomly rename database columns. :-)

With PDO, I could force all the keys to be lowercase with the following:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_LOWER);
```

It seems like something should be similar in the Symfony2 `/app/config/config.yml` file, but I've been unable to find such an option documented online. Since Doctrine wraps PDO, is there a way to pass the **`ATTR_CASE`** option in somehow?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125725/doctrine-column-names-case-sensitivity) appears to be related at first glace, but (a) isn't using Doctrine 2 and (b) doesn't settle the matter in the yml config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DBAL connection options can contain a parameter named **`driverOptions`**. This should be the same as the array of attributes which can be given to the PDO constructor (see: [Custom Driver Options](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html#custom-driver-options)). Add it to `doctrine.dbal.aademo_connection`

Comment: Am I doing this right? `driverOptions: {"PDO::ATTR_CASE" : "PDO::CASE_LOWER"}` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I think you'll need to use the values of those constants: `driverOptions: {8 : 2}`

Comment: In Symfony2 this parameter is called `options`, not `driverOptions` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13299382/1274733)