# Correct way to set the driverOptions for Doctrine DBAL configuration in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have set **driverOptions** in the config file as mentioned in the doctrine DBAL documentation.

But this gives an error

1/1 InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "driverOptions" under "doctrine.dbal.connections.pdoDevCon"

My config file is

```
dbal:
  default_connection: pdoDevCon
  connections:
    pdoDevCon:
      driver:   %dev_database_driver%    # <
      host:     %dev_database_host%      # |
      port:     %dev_database_port%      # | Defined in
      user:     %dev_database_user%      # |
      password: %dev_database_password%  # <   
      charset:  UTF8
      driverOptions: {3: 2}
      mapping_types:
        enum: string
        set: string

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
     pdoDevCon:
        connection: pdoDevCon
        mappings:
          AcmeDemoBundle: ~
          AcmeHelloBundle: ~
```

I am using **PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE as 3 PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION as 2**, it does not work even if i use the strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration

> DoctrineBundle supports all parameters that default Doctrine drivers
>   accept, **converted to the XML or YAML naming standards that Symfony
>   enforces**. See the Doctrine DBAL documentation for more information.

There is no `driverOptions` in symfony yml configuration file, just `options`

Comment: This can be updated, since symfony 3.2 you can use PHP constatnts in yml files.
So confguration now can be:

```
      connections:
          default:
              options:
                !php/const:PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT: 1000000000
```

Comment: There is tiny change in how to use the PHP constants since Symfony 3.4, https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files

Answer (score 4):

I'm not using Symfony but I was using `Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection()`.

I had to side step the `DriverManager` and do this song and dance to specify a connection timeout (`ATTR_TIMEOUT`):

```
function buildDbConn($config, $timeout) {
    $params = $config->toArray();
    $params['driverOptions'] = [
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => intval($timeout),
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ];
    $driver = new Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver;
    return new Doctrine\DBAL\Connection($params, $driver);
}
```

I always need a pdo_mysql driver, this could be configurable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this option from the yml.
The thing is that you nezd to use the const value:

The option param will be copied as driver option dont worry

The int is 2

options
    2: 10

works for me i. Symfony 3.4 and 4.2